# Linux BFQ Scheduler with SSD

Tags: linux, ssd, io

In the past I had always been advised by [resources](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD#I.2FO_Scheduler) that I can get a performance boost when using SSDs by switching from the default Linux scheduler CFQ to one such as deadline or noop.

Today after a fresh install of Manjaro linux I looked to see which scheduler was being used by running: `cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler` and I was greeted by the following:

```
noop deadline cfq [bfq]
```

I did a bit of searching and I found out that BFQ is a new IO scheduler in linux.

What are it's performance characteristics when it comes to use with SSD's and in particular is it still advisable to switch to using noop or deadline schedulers?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/11/bfq-loads-programs-extremely-fast-under-heavy-disk-io-workloads-ubuntu/

Haven't tried it myself (downloading now). But this website might be what you're looking for.